# ecdf plot in R with categorical data for comparison

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, ecdf, proportions

I would like to understand why my `ecdf` plot starts with values below 0. I wanted to create a plot that shows how many occurrences happened in fixed intervals of 5 minutes in all `sessions` to make a comparison among them. The data used for the calculation contains the following columns:

1. `onset`: this is a time in seconds when the participant did something relevant
2. `session`: the session from 1 to 7 when the data point was detected

**My data.frame**

```
my_df<-data.frame(structure(list(onset = c(419.958, 423.417, 
424.626, 428.13, 430.027, 843.931, 1050.858, 1272.617, 541.678, 
542.573, 587.0435181, 587.926, 589.208, 594.1247675, 595.3831742, 
639.0038589, 845.732, 850.223, 915.6195364, 1133.057568, 1255.64, 
342.742, 346.73, 348.742, 612.45, 906.3799686, 908.106, 983.642, 
984.733, 988.328, 1398.03, 75.026, 301.500822, 305.572, 306.8735654, 
952.024, 963.854, 1233.442, 206.192, 737.176, 739.983, 859.611, 
985.878, 987.32, 988.76, 1015.397, 1076.659, 1079.094, 1165.905, 
1329.551784, 175.034, 178.6396637, 244.669, 333.707, 442.462, 
955.194, 1205.312, 1207.426038, 1341.025783, 1347.837, 73.346, 
305.3205421, 584.2203571, 938.998, 476.503, 1314.698, 760.994, 
767.379, 534.771, 702.142, 1086.282, 1401.191, 878.719, 351.5632867, 
470.1344892, 759.584, 709.3478891, 393.8755592, 869.54, 89.23031499, 
307.82, 301.4076123, 877.156, 1089.802, 409.2466698, 92.984, 
1070.552, 72.545, 74.543, 81.221, 84.58877061, 87.674, 1162.993, 
1336.56, 1359.987, 461.987, 715.036, 480.563, 831.4982492, 556.1421114, 
788.4495002, 432.1880111, 1149.172553, 591.5281761, 1373.055841, 
1130.26, 963.838, 722.25, 170.372, 1135.572, 887.72, 1394.118, 
1042.509, 267.758, 398.276, 1166.95, 1051.554481, 1241.738, 952.6, 
1138.465, 404.73, 445.14, 859.54, 598.35, 624.91, 1057.769261, 
1101.312, 1008.07, 942.29, 166.784, 920.53, 263.784, 190.6, 195.91, 
555.693, 309.12, 612.99, 945.815, 560.857, 772.58, 349.1350516, 
22.76625335, 51.06740959, 376.5554969, 549.66, 27.951, 895.0516383, 
756.6, 16.47455788, 933.285, 1042.01, 1114.048, 1155, 1236.01, 
1004.684721, 723.3284434, 1052.09, 600.073, 1408.832, 719.5726666, 
1233.523, 94.44, 706.673, 207.91, 880.85, 242.03, 905.79, 1158.895, 
1043.589522, 88.60445029, 815.78, 528.68, 749.415, 256.4979168, 
1345.045414, 325.94, 1245.09, 1082.979, 0.591062169, 779.95, 
398.451, 405.4671198, 1079.881, 1111.63022, 234.3040133, 166.98, 
400.974229, 1033.913, 971.136, 1027.643043, 407.66, 753.365, 
1210.787, 1054.719, 161.782, 804.55, 711.413, 714.4283668, 1061.309, 
1055.14806, 30.13, 859.941, 651.643, 1008.925, 1011.013183, 79.74091208, 
373.904292, 1173.3, 164.149, 594.63, 802.7881328, 807.36, 626.3, 
784.25, 343.78, 816.86, 1038.249, 431.916, 1065.96, 639.7356609, 
844.6434458, 317.8537066, 523.4468384, 852.903, 916.4645446, 
750.516, 57.189359, 1125.110546, 606.19, 442.59, 318.36, 195.28, 
315.96, 332.86, 202.36, 1384.924986, 1074.18, 179.21, 114.694, 
339.1427164, 91.13003382, 782.03, 982.76, 1362.873, 512.693, 
388.4554732, 777.93, 911.8, 403.65, 777.54, 780.1383775, 303.0710363, 
410.8483636, 920.824, 1111.921122, 30.66302216, 43.83805816, 
775.7942561, 24.129, 1225.869, 321.86, 867.45, 487.6, 1357.566, 
340.136, 21.502, 441.593, 429.045, 761.215, 778.16, 336.41, 763.987, 
763.932, 262.01, 1106.63, 810.428927, 1050.608, 335.91, 137.0250512, 
634.0603696, 530.74, 680.873, 682.19, 310.4631946, 757.5182392, 
976.49, 821.69, 641.996, 416.9328327, 183.3713033, 607.09, 308.5548033, 
521.21, 800.52, 484.664, 1063.243, 281.0756142, 1189.435149, 
89.3254191, 91.648, 694.3260997, 1307.731, 581.5975231, 442.23, 
537.31, 826.2710512, 844.31, 671.31, 699.53, 431.687, 888.6214422, 
990.656, 1382.185, 465.7687543, 255.220891, 1098.487, 1102.5, 
1056.51, 623.1303318, 400.962, 610.61, 715.01, 252.1641262, 1123.418, 
1393.431816, 531.4498803, 176, 316.6691259, 1253.43, 368.4159373, 
743.2329046, 603.56, 348.8391861, 349.43, 1023.725625, 366.7135092, 
436.007, 467.453, 978.67, 1382.693585, 1330.083989, 631.0259279, 
382.7957552, 700.07, 703.653, 40.5, 400.65, 866.87, 850.33, 1174.77, 
1008.499849, 306.073, 234.0320764, 955.9046918, 1244.351219, 
853.4086587, 1257.05, 24.056, 44.485, 670.87, 801.7067697, 1182.34, 
618.799188, 67.22588222, 60.247, 1023.641, 636.031, 871.35, 171, 
196.6558084, 316.301, 325.395, 556.2028843, 564.866, 1139.452, 
282.509044, 1134.356, 621.5851968, 485.3493734, 17.984, 293.74, 
356.1189141, 1049.827859, 1282.688, 627.738, 194.43, 1330.596, 
1129.564599, 475.526, 295.38, 750.38, 914.179, 987.1487356, 138.663, 
873.31, 193.72, 645.23, 1301.059183, 14.23005285, 191.72759, 
260.121, 189.2461395, 191.7485783, 344.0350014, 455.1056168, 
1082.09, 181.48, 541.1336122, 463.61, 993.03, 1134.087091, 846.41, 
815.183, 1274.385261, 419.5513745, 494.163, 708.1598891, 775.63, 
631.161822, 1373.325796, 995.994, 603.97, 651.63, 875.657, 358.5, 
510.7800657, 628.1489384, 1182.122, 1271.511799, 67.503, 368.019724, 
160.6188558, 186.134, 526.4936007, 1365.173666, 317.185, 565.27, 
861.8073684, 1327.51, 604.474011, 683.74, 1108.716582, 68.547, 
1116.468, 70.40178512, 460.525, 586.8584482, 10.76086505, 1361.807329, 
627.2194929, 297.8096376, 318.3739772, 335.1867344, 783.722, 
285.83, 950.4771688, 114.16, 221.463, 6.187, 1326.570733, 81.85864697, 
483.787, 68.4266266, 85.274, 83.276, 90.20083462, 1069.43, 48.01708675, 
777.9838986, 261.029, 698.81, 626.32, 1136.279247, 183.5600647, 
526.55, 1071.918, 559.30382, 555.42, 1171.914, 1374.179, 869.49, 
629.41, 974.252, 976.301, 621.417, 126.28, 128.439, 588.0531995, 
312.3986016, 444.3212043, 1141.792, 169.578, 156.7112265, 590.135, 
435.0665518, 38.83728047, 784.721, 756.41, 658.86, 153.189, 493.83, 
772.304, 1146.728, 646.948, 777.2046221, 603.352, 400.0432132, 
852.278, 748.37, 653.371, 760.41, 1146.289, 155.6224346, 428.347, 
512.7254462, 872.991, 615.387, 357.4154169, 863.116, 967.723, 
1064.11, 629.155, 649.702, 655.255, 696.06, 698.1974897, 859.326, 
863.918, 1056.754, 1058.132, 1121.9, 1134.503, 193.1, 208.75, 
280.71, 289.74, 457.723114, 519.6791161, 533.98894, 541.06, 544.86, 
787.141, 902.0889705, 916.973, 918.08, 935.0711773, 1079.819616, 
118.0665907, 329.7, 351.6286566, 360.735, 370.94, 411.2, 651.2377016, 
831.96, 978.211, 1004.277, 1016.11, 1377.162242, 331.6813239, 
884.93, 67.04, 237.821, 262.633, 318.672, 321.506, 330.2701647, 
1383.633, 101.0584042, 620.1882006, 248.5892259, 515.7342561, 
528.721, 642.719, 676.929, 698.6897511, 699.7895188, 768.931, 
771.2597811, 1006.70645, 1054.143848, 1162.893739, 81.991, 133.088, 
389.9668307, 414.756, 925.789, 928.233, 933.449, 827.1840634, 
1328.301855, 308.4447468, 620.1840055, 176.488, 485.95, 1128.35, 
1129.436, 1198.463, 1199.53, 356.691019, 1122.19, 411.9827411, 
634.698, 639.563, 1025.78, 1028.48, 1029.919, 1355.971, 1201.944, 
1204.96, 1209.108, 549.732, 761.1617458, 763.088, 764.166, 15.684, 
314.16, 779.3716376, 1063.282, 277.92, 484.256, 584.42, 631.757, 
741.015, 763.723, 765.006, 1221.475, 204.37, 206.16, 211.28, 
214.025, 223.96, 291.1623684, 659.37, 660.54, 747.582386, 785.12, 
872.6, 886.41, 1125.253, 373.36, 380.4072016, 381.54, 413.574, 
416.103, 482.444, 494.0043482, 633.17, 1093.33, 1177.102, 1400.078, 
192.5836367, 324.3398598, 685.16, 1142.004506, 1144.92, 1159.452555, 
1160.521591, 1168.89, 1187.29, 1290.728906, 1302.249, 46.08, 
63.38, 278.4, 301.8126773, 224.538, 248.241, 256.021, 320.062, 
336.684, 419.19, 641.168, 819.731, 1040.119, 99.663, 115.4468337, 
144.8157385, 625.417673, 629.553, 630.165, 674.293, 675.65, 852.614663, 
1067.134884, 19.99061615, 106.555, 419.033, 562.918, 907.249, 
936.13, 945.568, 717.048, 630.122, 640.2, 85.38039303, 633.082, 
716.79, 1126.233, 1127.46, 382.93, 267.537, 269.435, 389.289, 
440.825, 631.222, 838.924, 991.388, 992.348, 1027.339, 1030.404, 
1062.412, 1133.475, 1147.957, 1227.83, 1281.203, 1352.052, 279.301, 
282.02, 284.72, 393.0296395, 614.982, 630.928, 644.23, 861.053, 
891.5914327, 1105.18825, 40.99, 353.878665, 415.096, 477.502, 
535.67, 760.68, 762.34, 862.95, 975.745, 991.813, 1245.92053, 
1378.564812, 1234.56664, 356.06, 326.671, 453.6129182, 854.4366754, 
1058.38, 1077.77, 1128.47, 56.958, 263.4947463, 71.333, 420.46, 
430.0082436, 59.9193677, 77.605, 1274.917, 695.813, 1375.24149, 
748.6642977, 1278.53, 1159.537, 482.5159065, 715.2000502, 1083.790317, 
893.26, 1151.102243, 672.18, 1098.584, 786.142, 790.137782, 792.08, 
821.295, 1150.754, 1088, 1168.118, 1186.572579, 1279.724564, 
16.42, 21.73447847, 24.37078332, 31.742, 33.885, 47.93714042, 
62.342, 65.133, 181.958, 199.782, 570.151, 581.721, 601.485, 
620.67, 713.97, 977.613, 994.944, 1172.86, 1178.559, 383.9234696, 
396.4047142, 424.468, 1033.645, 1136.733, 1216.784, 1219.156, 
1220.725, 1246.1, 337.5389917, 250.0248508, 260.2380502, 329.817, 
380.1058472, 484.6447318, 776.989, 788.478317, 867.992, 981.1047375, 
1063.19493, 1355.555432, 144.295, 291.3075882, 311.7144273, 338.868, 
495.8031489, 510.9534887, 527.907, 690.252, 949.1086647, 986.31, 
1285.32538, 1317.209039, 1331.096795, 1364.287925, 89.92544158, 
489.6954457, 1193.227268, 110.436421, 222.215, 116.12, 699.026, 
868.49, 674.492, 1194.408, 108.2262354, 1053.867849, 449.411, 
696.909, 828.605, 133.828, 331.1686937, 355.3361644, 532.1, 879.9183715, 
880.94, 1114.573238, 1115.691, 113.5902259, 887.7675307, 119.813, 
183.5095014, 1253.75, 636.794, 310.5291736, 1075.98, 363.6291615, 
1327.401596, 922.43, 473.09159, 955.576, 25.198, 484.813, 354.210055, 
1366.781785, 520.011, 85.407, 568.643, 578.723, 309.561, 1020.645, 
873.598, 1068.215, 183.17, 653.998, 155.34, 650.19, 1012.182, 
512.56, 409.3, 315.38, 1016.766, 532.8887932, 1258.27, 923.64, 
1379.18, 1028.107, 1311.618882, 238.371, 837.97, 481.480923, 
487.82, 900.88, 1035.136, 1040.705, 1056.72, 94.561, 617, 211.44, 
88.037, 1360.179, 489.21, 1052.933, 423.71, 1057.78, 302.05, 
1360.33, 174.5403451, 1071.41, 637.93, 97.253, 639.825, 1132.558959, 
1023.122, 254.44, 554.21, 1064.464, 1071.855, 217.4443965, 1303.61, 
1365.15, 300.25, 1315.823679, 1366.011748, 653.76, 660.41, 369.3562394, 
1079.568, 1317.54, 768.15, 527.955, 1005.583, 1011.7, 1210.63, 
527.0529424, 815.3011492, 1105.979, 1107.524, 611.13, 270.6187551, 
514.1471662, 552.3765673, 691.0312454, 851.374, 102.7661212, 
677.64, 250.3283731, 773.7930228, 1120.224644, 470.17, 360.4814181, 
157.63, 338.96, 468.0820752, 359.809, 1091.86, 1035.868214, 556.453, 
414.84, 451.28, 518.48, 1045.004, 704.8, 483.83, 1128.933, 0.008404827, 
0, 713.85, 1269.021639, 1275.278685, 1281.049, 1286.957, 1292.173312, 
998.586, 1002.729995, 1055.903, 1069.064, 1151.04, 1182.05, 1336.93, 
1350.627, 1402.408, 112.139, 123.5, 128.251223, 131.172, 170.115, 
298.513, 308.764, 325.89, 331.266, 337.798, 350.555, 359.915, 
385.89, 403.185, 408.156, 517.602, 608.081, 612.524, 622.751, 
801.2, 805.887, 811.093, 813.712, 948.563, 960.331, 1129.594, 
1168.39, 1343.742, 1348.533, 1388.121, 50.691, 108.847, 127.945, 
328.949, 466.625, 479.575, 509.352, 613.295, 642.126, 646.615, 
650.49, 749.351, 130.234, 143.442, 200.7657668, 213.8909377, 
217.074, 239.508194, 277.041, 476.1736943, 501.821, 532.516, 
547.492, 560.929, 567.7104084, 594.572, 615.3132863, 628.8239445, 
700.571, 727.558, 742.8921655, 750.966, 780.4867713, 785.3392965, 
791.616, 797.034, 801.551, 816.848, 833.8648716, 839.601, 846.8548622, 
957.335, 963.3353684, 1013.083, 1046.356522, 1116.771884, 1151.436, 
1155.106, 1184.592, 1199.125, 1269.394, 1272.529018, 1281.594, 
1332.930304, 46.245, 63.654, 156.076, 244.329, 297.919, 301.637, 
333.555, 422.352, 476.809, 520.319, 523.901, 535.066, 469.2883534, 
730.585, 884.748, 890.129, 952.18, 452.29, 461.844, 476.259, 
488.807, 334.8465017, 1231.182, 496.015, 515.68, 542.249, 551.681, 
555.198, 573.22, 633.3539405, 548.39549, 720.562, 785.31, 793.441, 
800.177, 805.815, 1238.014, 2.758, 607.99, 1058.217889, 24.899, 
53.097, 103.637, 107.512, 316.169, 421.334, 437.623, 456.48, 
461.54, 467.497, 486.554, 493.7896717, 498.39, 1014.521, 500.865, 
506.817, 542.868, 551.585, 579.787626, 583.2943703, 629.3395676, 
633.638, 672.9405181, 680.701, 684.7385414, 691.598, 939.3966533, 
1003.848133, 601.79, 219.462), session = c("s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", 
"s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s4", "s1", "s6", "s7", "s7", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s7", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s4", "s1", "s7", "s1", "s2", "s3", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s2", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s2", 
"s1", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s6", "s6", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s7", "s6", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s2", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s6", 
"s1", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s2", "s3", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s1", "s6", 
"s4", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s6", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s4", 
"s1", "s1", "s4", "s6", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s6", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s4", "s3", "s4", 
"s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s6", "s1", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s3", "s4", 
"s3", "s3", "s1", "s3", "s1", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s6", "s2", "s1", 
"s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s2", "s3", "s1", "s2", "s3", 
"s3", "s1", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s1", "s3", "s2", "s2", 
"s1", "s6", "s7", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s1", "s1", 
"s3", "s3", "s6", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s3", "s2", "s1", "s2", 
"s1", "s1", "s3", "s2", "s3", "s1", "s6", "s3", "s1", "s3", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s2", "s1", 
"s4", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", 
"s7", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s3", 
"s1", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s6", "s2", "s1", "s2", "s3", 
"s3", "s1", "s7", "s1", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s4", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s4", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", 
"s3", "s4", "s6", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s6", "s6", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s7", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s6", "s6", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s6", "s2", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s1", "s1", 
"s3", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s1", "s2", "s4", "s4", "s2", "s1", "s1", 
"s3", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s7", "s6", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s1", "s2", 
"s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s4", "s1", "s1", "s5", 
"s5", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", 
"s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s4", "s4", "s4", "s6", "s6", "s7", "s7", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s6", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s1", "s3", "s5", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", 
"s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s6", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s3", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s6", "s6", 
"s6", "s6", "s6", "s7", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s7", 
"s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s3", 
"s3", "s6", "s1", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s4", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s7", "s2", "s3", "s2", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s2", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s7", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s6", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s3", "s1", "s7", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s4", 
"s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", 
"s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", 
"s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", 
"s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", 
"s2", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", 
"s2", "s1", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s2", "s4", "s6", 
"s6", "s6", "s6", "s6", "s6", "s6", "s1", "s3", "s6", "s6", "s6", 
"s6", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s1", 
"s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", 
"s7", "s1", "s1", "s4", "s1")), row.names = c(NA, -1141L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

In order to visualize the data points I

- formatted data points in seconds to minutes for the column `onset`
- created custom breaks for the y-axis
- plotted the data with `cdf`

```
## Set up function for minor ticks
every_nth <- function(x, nth, empty = TRUE, inverse = FALSE)
{
if (!inverse) {
if(empty) {
x[1:nth == 1] <- ""
x
} else {
x[1:nth != 1]
}
} else {
if(empty) {
x[1:nth != 1] <- ""
x
} else {
x[1:nth == 1]
}
}
}


## Define a formatter function - converts time from seconds into minutes to a string
timeHM_formatter <- function(x) {
  h <- floor(x/60)
  m <- floor(x %% 60)
  lab <- sprintf("%d", h) # Format the strings as HH:MM
  return(lab)
}

## Create custom breaks
custom_breaks1 <- seq(0.00, 1.00,0.10)      #breaks for y-axis

## Plot data
my_plot<-my_df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x=onset, col=session))+ 
  stat_ecdf(size=1,geom = "line")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1500, by = 300),labels = timeHM_formatter)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=custom_breaks1, labels=every_nth(custom_breaks1,2, inverse=TRUE)) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA),
          axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = .5),
          axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = .5),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size=12),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size=12),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(),
          panel.spacing.y = unit(0.5, "cm"),
          legend.text=element_text(size=12))+
  labs(title="Female",col ="Session")+
  ylab("Proportion\n")+ 
  xlab("\nTime (min)")

my_plot
```

The plot I got is this one:

[image]

I do not quite understand why did I get values between 0 and 0 (I marked them in yellow). Is this because of the fact that there are 2 data points with 0 values? If that is the case, how do I know how far shall I go on the x-axis to catch it? Most and for all, I am not sure if I did catch what I wanted in my top question which is understand how many data points fall in sequential 5-minute intervals across all sessions. Maybe I was wrong in assuming the `ecdf` graph is not what I should apply.

Comment: I don't think it is starting below 0, it is just how the plot was constructed add this to the plot so you can start the graph at 0 `+ scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))`